# Encrypting message from php to .net

Tags: php, .net, encryption, httprequest

I need to send a request from a php server to a .NET one.
This request have to be cypted, so I thought about

- Serializing the params
- Cypting
- Base64 encode to put it as HTTP request

Here how I would do in php

```
$url = 'http://my.server.net';
$params = array('var1' => 5, 'var2' => 'machin', 'var3' => 'chose');
$serialized = json_encode($params);
$crypted = encrypt($serialized, $salt);
$request = $url.'?'.base64_encode($crypted);
```

`encrypt()` would encrypt the serialized params with flavoring.

Questions are

1. Which functions should I use to encrypt my message for it to be
   easily decrypted with .net ?
2. Is json a good serialization choice for .net ?

*I know nothing about .net, that will be done by other guys*

Comment: Can you throw SSL at the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For question one

- **PHP side** I think you can use the openssl extension of php http://php.net/manual/fr/book.openssl.php. It brings you a powerful API to do what you want.
- **.NET side** You can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx or http://www.dart.com/sockets-net-api-library.aspx

## For question 2:

json is a good serialisation tool but a bit lossy as it is typeless.
So two solutions here :

- you know that the .net application will share the same class architecture as yours so using `serialize()` is good.
- you do not know that or you know that it will be developped other way so json_encode is the best way to do that. I just want to point out the fact that if you five it as GET you will be limited to 255 chars instead of infinite if you chose a POST request.
  Moreover you have to urlencode your json datas if you want them to be readable

To send a POST request instead of a GET you can have a look at this script :
http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm

Comment: Thank you for the `GET` 255 chars limit notice. Actually I base64 encode the resulting json (forgot to mention it in the example) so I should not need to url_encode.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to do it in javascript (that's not a problem). I'm going to look through OpenSSL documentation, but I don't know much about encryption techniques and are you sure there is an implementation built within .net ?

Comment: For encryption, there is always an openssl extension in every language. I'm looking for it in msnd and post the link in my answer.

Comment: Some kind of salted hash, where the salt is shared between the two servers but not publicly known is a really simple kind of 'encryption', but I guess it depends on how secure you need it to be. Also, JSON is categorically not typeless - "The types represented in JSON are strings, numbers, booleans, object, arrays, and null", from json.org

Comment: salted hash is not encryption, it is hashing : you cannot reverse a hashcode.
JSON is lossy : classnames (so types), structures (in c++ for example) are forgot, and apart from magic overriding (JSONSerialize in php5.4) you cannot pass private attributes by direct input in json_encode.

Answer (score 1):

Your question are answers.

You can use `JSON`, `XML` for sending data from `PHP` to `.NET`.
The `json` is sending faster response than `XML`.

Yes `JSON` is good choice for serialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx